# How is this fact implicated?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field and $\overline{K}$ its algebraic closure, then we define the $n$-dimensional affine space as 
$$\mathbb{A}^{n}=\{(x_1, \ldots, x_{n})\mid x_1, \ldots, x_{n} \in \overline{K}\}$$

So we consider the projective space $X=\mathbb{P}^n$ which is defined by

$$(\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus \{\vec{o}\}) / \sim$$

where the equivalence relation is as follows, let $x,y \in \mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus \{\vec{o}\}$ then $x\sim y$ if
there exists $\lambda \in K$ such that $x= \lambda y$.

Therefore we can give $X$ the Zariski topology, hence a open set in $X$ is the complement of an algebraic homogeneous set (the zero locus of homogeneous polynomials), denoted by $D_f$. Given this we can construct a structure sheaf for $X$, to do this we define the ring

$$\mathcal{O}(D_g)=\{ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} : \partial f= \partial g\}$$

so then it makes sense to put

$$\mathcal{O}(U)= \bigcap_{D_g \subset U}\mathcal{O}(D_g)$$

and to get the one of the affine space $\mathbb{A}^{n}$ we just consider the embedding

$$\varphi_{i}:\mathbb{A}^{n} \to X$$

such that

$$\varphi_{i}(x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1})=(x_1:x_2: \ldots:x_{i-1}:1:x_i:\ldots: x_{n+1})$$

Next we note that $\varphi_{i}(\mathbb{A}^n) \simeq \mathbb{A}^n$ and $\varphi_{i}(\mathbb{A}^n)  \hookrightarrow X$.

My question is, Can we conclude that  $\mathcal{O_{\mathbb{A}^n}} \simeq \mathcal{O_{\varphi_{i}(\mathbb{A}^n)}} $ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a few errors, but I think your question is, do we have an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{Y}=\mathcal{O}_{A^n}$, where the isomorphism is induced by $\phi_i$? The answer is yes. Namely there is an isomorphism of polynomial in $n$ variables and homogenous polynomials up to inversion by $x_i$, by setting $x_i=1$.

Comment: Yes but can you elaborate more please :) is because in general case of an arbitrary topological space my assertion is not true so I want to know what's the thing that works here :)

Comment: There is a inverse, $Y\to \mathbb{A}^n$, given by $(z_1:\dots z_{n+1})\to (z_1/z_i, \dots z_{n+1}/z_i)$. This establishes an algebraic isomorphism of the varieties. This induces an isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_Y=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n}$. I'm not sure what you mean in an arbitary topological sheaf, since you don't really have a structure sheaf. Maybe $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(X)$? But that is additionally preserved by homoemorphism.

Comment: Ok so let me edit because I do have a explicit sheaf for X just give a second :)

Comment: Is the one induced by homogeneous polynomials do you recognise it ?

Comment: Then just a second to edit my post

Comment: Ready, is now clear?

Comment: So then what is the induced isomorphism that you said ? Or what can be done ?

Comment: @Kamina  What can be done?

Comment: Which is then the induced isomorphism?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: @Kamina I have edited my post

Comment: @Kamina Can you tell me which is the induced isomorphism ?